# Open link in same page and once link is open, execute some code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several pop-ups on home page. I open and close them by selecting them with ID and using fadeIn() and fadeOut(). Now I want to open a specific pop-up by clicking on link from another window? For example, if from that new window I click on 'Pop Up 1', I want home page to open and then show 'Pop Up 1'.

I tried using this code below but while writing this code I realized that the script gets reloaded and thus my function of loading a pop-up does not work.

So my question is, is there some elegant solution you could recommend to show element in one page while a link that specifies which element has to be shown is in another?

```
$("#galleryNav a").on('click', function() {
    window.open("/pixeleyes",'_self',false);

    setTimeout(function() {
        var popToShow = $(this).attr('data-pop');
        $(".text-content-outer").hide();
        $("#" + popToShow).fadeIn();            
    }, 5000);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea might work is

When you are opening a new page using the below line then send some parameter or hash value with it.

```
window.open("/pixeleyes",'_self',false);
```

like

```
window.open("/pixeleyes#openpopup",'_self',false);
```

Then in the page ready of this page check if the hash exists open the popup otherwise do nothing.
Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a good solution. I was thinking maybe it would be possible to use form and pass variables that way but this is even better, thanks. Anyway, I will wait for more answers just in case before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#galleryNav a").on('click', function() {
    window.open("/pixeleyes#showpopup",'_self',false);

});
```

## showpopup could be anything that you want to open as popup...